# Load from private Image in Softlayer

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to implement the loadFromImage function using Softlayer java API. When I test on control.softlayer.com, a private image is not being listed. 
Do I need to load a private image to my server first? 
Then, load the image on the server? If not, Can you guide me the right procedure ?  Can I have any sample code to implement?

Thank you 
Mike

[Load From Image Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmDzq.png)

Comment: Have you added the image to the image manager? http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/import-image

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you don’t have any “private image” in your account, please see in Control Portal to confirm this:

> https://control.softlayer.com/devices/images

(filter by “private images”)

**To create a new image from portal:**

- Go to https://control.softlayer.com/devices
- Select a server from the list
- Once ready the **“Device List”** window, select **“Create Image Template”** from **“Actions”** right menu. A standard image will be created. This image will be listed in your private images.

**API examples:**

Meanwhile for API, I will provide some REST requests that may help you:

- **To create a new standard image, execute:**

URL:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/5464742/createArchiveTransaction.json

Method: POST

Json:
*-----------------------
{
  "parameters": [
    "my-new-standard-image-name ",
    [
      {
        "id": 6862924,
        "complexType": "SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device"
      }
    ],
    "api note"
  ]
}
*-----------------------

where: 

" my-new-standard-image-name " is the group name for the archive
"6862924" A computing instance block device's unique ID
"api note" is A long note describing the image template
"5464742" is the id of virtual server
```

How to get the “block device's unique ID”?

```
Please, execute:

https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/[Virtual_Guest_ID]/getBlockDevices?objectFilter={"blockDevices":{"bootableFlag":{"operation": "1"}}}&objectMask=mask[id]
```

After executing the **“SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::createArchiveTransaction”** a new transaction will be created in the server, please wait some minutes until it is completed.

Reference: http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/createArchiveTransaction

- **How to load from image via API?**

URL:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/[Virtual_Guest_ID]/reloadOperatingSystem
```

Method: POST

```
    Json:

*----------------------------    
{
  "parameters": [
    "f610b52f9fce12ef4fc37d6e9f5fe77a",
    {
      "imageTemplateId": 931371
    }
  ]
}
*----------------------------
```

Where:

```
“f610b52f9fce12ef4fc37d6e9f5fe77a” is the token (The token will remain active for 10 minutes)
“931371” the image template to use
```

But, How to get the token for our above configuration?

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/[Virtual_Guest_ID]/reloadOperatingSystem
    Method: GET
```

References:

> http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/reloadOperatingSystem
>   http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/learning/introduction-image-templates
>   http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/faq/what-standard-image-template
>   http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/faq/what-flex-image
>   http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/create-standard-image
>   http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/create-flex-image

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. :)

Comment: I got 2 more questions. What is the functional difference between BootfromImage and LoadfromImage ? If we upload own image to local disk using ftp, can we reload the image with those two functions?

Comment: This documentation can help you: https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/faqs/5#1130
https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/faqs/5